# GitHub - добавление отдельного файла с чужого репозитория в свой

Tags: git, github

Вот есть допустим репозиторий  Бутстрапа на гитхаб - github.com/Ma5tercontrol/bootstrap.
мне от туда нужно лишь файл _reboot.scss, но отдельно его я не могу добавить к себе, добавляется все вместе сразу!!
Есть ли способ сделать это?

ps
если кому то не понятно, хочу добавить файл который в красным кружке!!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а добавляется весь бутстрап!!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у вас проблемы со скачиванием файлов или с формулировкой вопроса? если второе, то внесите уточнения, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: 1. - Выделите нужный фрагмент. 2. - Клик правой кнопкой мыши. 3. - "Копировать". 4. - Выбрать, куда копировать. 5. - Клик правой кнопкой мыши. 6. - "Вставить".
???

Comment: Человек просто не смог сформулировать вопрос, он спрашивает, как смерджить ветки только по одному файлу, то есть перенести только один файл в свой репо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В гите в принципе нет возможности переноса одного файла. Только если такие варианты

1. Скопировать этот файл себе и запушить
2. Сделать черепик комита, которым был добавлен этот файл (перенесутся все изменения в этом комите)
3. Мердж ветки, тогда вообще все различия попадут к вам

Думаю, вам подходит только пункт 1., по-другому, как я считаю, никак.